# How to add title without losing option selected in form select multiple ( django )

Tags: django

Done.
My implementation on edit:

```
<select name="course" required id="id_course" multiple>
{% for id, value in form.course.field.choices %}
    <option title="{{value}}" value="{{ id }}" {% if id in form.course.value %} selected {% endif %}{% if id|slugify in form.course.value %} selected {% endif %}>{{ value }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

and implementation on create new object:

```
<select name="course" required id="id_course" multiple>
{% for id, value in form.course.field.choices %}
    <option title="{{value}}" value="{{ id }}" {% if id|slugify in form.course.value %} selected {% endif %}>{{ value }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

*look type In the case of editing c `form.course.value` comes ['3', '4',] and when creating an object comes [3,4,]. `id` is always a number

---

Here are my models.py:

```
class Student(models.Model):

course = models.ManyToManyField(
    CourseInstance)
```

Here are my views.py:

```
class StudentUpdate(UpdateView):
model = Student
fields = '__all__'
```

student_form.html:

```
<form action="" method="post" id = "group-form">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">    
                {{ field.label_tag }}
                {% if 'курсы:' in field.label_tag|lower  %}
                    <div>
                        <a href="{% url 'GroupCreate'%}" id="add_group" onclick="return showAddPopup(this);">Добавить</a>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
                {{ field.errors }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10 pull-left">
                {% if 'курсы:' in field.label_tag|lower  %}

                {% comment %} {% load widget_tweaks %}
                {% render_field field class="help-title-on" %} {% endcomment %}
                
                <select name="course" required id="id_course" multiple>
                    {% with value=form.course.value %}
                    {% for value in form.course.field.choices.queryset %}
                    <option title="{{value}}" value="{{ value.id }}">{{ value }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% endwith %}
                </select>

                {% elif 'modelfield' not in field.name %}
                {{ field }}
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div> {% endfor %}


</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

When I render the form template this way, I lose the "course" selected, but the title is added. Tried to do with widget settings. I don't know how to refer to "option" in "select". How to assign:  option title="{{text_value}}"

[with title but lose selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M96cB.png)

[without title but with selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlbkd.png)

Comment: My implementation on edit:
`<select name="course" required id="id_course" multiple>
{% for id, value in form.course.field.choices %}
<option title="{{value}}" value="{{ id }}" {% if id in form.course.value %} selected {% endif %}{% if id|slugify in form.course.value %} selected {% endif %}>{{ value }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>`
and

Comment: and implementation on create new object:
`<select name="course" required id="id_course" multiple>
{% for id, value in form.course.field.choices %}
<option title="{{value}}" value="{{ id }}" {% if id|slugify in form.course.value %} selected {% endif %}>{{ value }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>`
*look type
In the case of editing c form.course.value comes ['3', '4',] and when creating an object comes [3,4,]. id is always a number